# Saving R objects not workspaces

Tags: r, workspace, rdata

i am completely new in R. 
I am trying to save a spatialdataframe and a normal data frame within the same object. when I am applying the code below, it saves the object as a R workspace, is it normal? i mean I wnated to obtain a .rda data instead. What i specifically want to do is to obtain an R data with those two objects. I want the spatialdataframe to keep its spatial charactheristics. Can someone help me?

```
##import a text table 
mcvfinal<-read.csv("dataCPWithAge.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",",dec=".") 

##reading the shapefile 
library(rgdal) polypc1 <- readOGR(".", "CP3poly_Matchingshp")   

##saving the two frames into the same object 
save(mcvfinal,polypc1,file="polypc.Rdata")
```

Comment: did the answer work out for you?

Comment: It worked out fine, I am just unable to view the content of the polypc.rds file. When i am doing he str(polypc), it cause an error to the system. it begins opening but nerver ends. – fine,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
saveRDS(list(mcvfinal,polypc1),file="polypc.rds")
```

Load:

```
foo = readRDS("polypc.rds")

# mcvfinal is foo[[1]]
# polypc1 is foo[[2]]
```

Comment: I tried it, but it is returning an error:the file was created but it cant be loaded. Pleas can you tell me the difference between .rda and .RDS exensions? Thanks again

Comment: Sorry i did not read the correct file. The file was succesfully loaded.

Comment: I am just unable to view the content of the polypc.rds file. When i am doing he str(polypc), it cause an error to the system. it begins opening but nerver ends.

Comment: Since the command was for saving 2 objects as a list, when you read the `polypc.rds` file, recall that `polypc[[1]]` would be the `mcvfinal` object and `polypc[[2]]` would be the `polypc` object. So try doing `str(polypc[[2]])`. And please *accept* the answer if it worked for you. Thanks!

Comment: Hi rmk,thanks a lot for your help. Sorry I am new in this forum and I do not know the rules. Finally it was a problem with the level of memory. Ot worked out perfectly.